# Template10 ThemeResource don't update only some part of HamburgerMenu

Tags: template10

I have a strange problem with template10 custom style, this is a [simple gif to show you](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFALY.gif). As you can see all the layout and the background automatically update, but the foreground of the NavButton and NavButtonChecked don't automatically do it, why?
And this is the code that I use:

```
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
        <Style TargetType="controls:HamburgerMenu">
            <Setter Property="HamburgerBackground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemChromeMediumColor}" />
            <Setter Property="HamburgerForeground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemBaseHighColor}" />
            <Setter Property="NavAreaBackground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemChromeMediumLowColor}" />
            <Setter Property="NavButtonBackground" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="NavButtonForeground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemBaseHighColor}" />
            <Setter Property="NavButtonHoverBackground" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="NavButtonHoverForeground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemBaseHighColor}" />
            <Setter Property="NavButtonPressedBackground" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="NavButtonPressedForeground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemBaseHighColor}" />
            <Setter Property="NavButtonCheckedBackground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemAccentColor}" />
            <Setter Property="NavButtonCheckedForeground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemAltHighColor}" />
            <Setter Property="NavButtonCheckedIndicatorBrush" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="VisualStateNarrowMinWidth" Value="{StaticResource NarrowMinWidth}" />
            <Setter Property="VisualStateNormalMinWidth" Value="{StaticResource NormalMinWidth}" />
            <Setter Property="VisualStateWideMinWidth" Value="{StaticResource WideMinWidth}" />
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>

    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dark">
        <Style TargetType="controls:HamburgerMenu">
            <Setter Property="HamburgerBackground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemChromeMediumColor}" />
            <Setter Property="HamburgerForeground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemBaseHighColor}" />
            <Setter Property="NavAreaBackground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemChromeMediumLowColor}" />
            <Setter Property="NavButtonBackground" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="NavButtonForeground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemBaseHighColor}" />
            <Setter Property="NavButtonHoverBackground" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="NavButtonHoverForeground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemBaseHighColor}" />
            <Setter Property="NavButtonPressedBackground" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="NavButtonPressedForeground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemBaseHighColor}" />
            <Setter Property="NavButtonCheckedBackground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemAccentColor}" />
            <Setter Property="NavButtonCheckedForeground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemBaseHighColor}" />
            <Setter Property="NavButtonCheckedIndicatorBrush" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="VisualStateNarrowMinWidth" Value="{StaticResource NarrowMinWidth}" />
            <Setter Property="VisualStateNormalMinWidth" Value="{StaticResource NormalMinWidth}" />
            <Setter Property="VisualStateWideMinWidth" Value="{StaticResource WideMinWidth}" />
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

How I can fix it?